# AdMob и метод setAdUnitId

Tags: android, java, admob

У офиц. документации google есть пример создания admob баннера со следующим кодом:

```
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
```

что такое `MY_AD_UNIT_ID` и откуда его взять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"MY_AD_UNIT_ID" это уникальный идентификатор вашего баннера, коий надо создать в панели управления на сайте adMob. Значение это типа String, соответственно получиться должно что-то типа:

```
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-345345/345345");
```